# Live widget generation for users

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

I have created a widget for users which they can embed to their site  using the following code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>  

<script src="http://www.socialfeastalpha.com/widget/xss_magic.js"></script> 

<div id="socialfeast-widget"></div>
```

I want users to be able to customized the widget according to their needs. 
any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks..

Comment: your second `script` tag is wrongly written and where is the code to embed and what customization?

Comment: u can add the code above to any webpage and ull get a widget 
i want U the user to have an option to change color ,width, height etc before embeding it to your website
hope u got me this time 
thnaks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple solution: Make the URL to the JS script actually generate a unique script for each user.

Better solution: Make your users call a callback from your script with some identification information, ala Google Analytics.